# Каким образом можно создать массив из enum перечисления?

Tags: c#, enum

Чтобы не создавать новую переменную вручную и присваивать каждый элемент enum.
enum Day = {"zzz", "sss",... }
Day one = Day.zzz;
Можно ли сделать одну переменную которая бы хранила сразу все значения enum. Массив из enum переменных например

Comment: `Enum.GetValues<SuperEnum>();`, если нужны строки, то преобразовывайте полученное в `string`.

Comment: ColorEnum[] colors = Enum.GetValues<ColorEnum>();так вот?

Comment: Ну вы попробуйте, или каждую строку будете спрашивать "так вот?".

Comment: Благодарю, дай бог вам здоровья ❤️